# Rare events modelling

Tags: logistic, generalized-linear-model, rare-events

I am trying to figure out the effect of two independant variables (country and device_type) on a binary dependant variable (conversions). I am running a logit regression on a dataset with only the independent categorical variables. Both of these variables have several values. The event (conversions) occurs approximately 0.2% of the time (on 750 000 observations).

I am trying to establish which country and device have the greatest effect on conversion.

For certain countries, the coefficients are significant, but I do not have any positive event for this country. How can this happen ? How can I establish if my model converged. I have no warning. Any help on the issue is appreciated.

I am using the glm procedure in R:
logit1 <- glm(conversions ~ device_type + country, data = reg_data)

this is a repost (under my name) of this [question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/261772/rare-events-modelling-value-of-coefficients):

Thank you,

Comment: I would use an extreme value distribution. The most likely choice would be the double exponential distribution.

Comment: Please don't repost your questions: just edit the original.

Comment: Thanks will try extreme value distribution. Will do next time. I couldn't add comments because it wasn't under my name.

Comment: Please visit http://stats.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts to merge your accounts.  BTW, it is not at all evident how the extreme value distribution would be relevant to a problem involving binary responses.  You might not want to chase that rabbit unless you get a more detailed explanation of what to do.